# Annotations get complicated in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, exception, testng

I have same sort of annotations my class hierarchy has some problems. I tried

```
@BeforeSuit
@BeforeClass
@BeforeTest
```

And all causes the same error. Here are my codes.

LoginPage

```
public class LoginPage extends BasePage {

public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}

@FindBy(id = "username")
private WebElement username;

@FindBy(id = "passwor")
private WebElement password;

@FindBy(id = "loginbutton")
private WebElement loginSubmitButton;

@FindBy(id = "wrong")
private WebElement errorBox;

private void loginAction(String username, String password) {
    this.username.sendKeys(username);
    this.password.sendKeys(password);
    this.loginSubmitButton.click();
}

public void invalidLogin(String username, String password) {
    this.loginAction(username, password);
}

public HomePage validLogin(String username, String password) {
    this.loginAction(username,password);
    return PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, HomePage.class);
}

public boolean isErrorBoxDisplayed() {
    return this.errorBox.isDisplayed();
}

public void clearForm() {
    this.username.clear();
    this.password.clear();
}
}
```

LoginPageTest

```
public class LoginPageTest extends BaseTest {

@Test(dataProvider = "credentials", dataProviderClass = CredentialsDataProvider.class)
public void login(Boolean isValid, String username, String password) throws InterruptedException {
    if (isValid) {
        this.homePage = this.loginPage.validLogin(username, password);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        assertThat(this.webDriver.getCurrentUrl(), is(equalTo(PropertyReader.getProperty("home_page"))));
    } else {
        this.loginPage.invalidLogin(username, password);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        assertThat(this.webDriver.getCurrentUrl(), is(equalTo(PropertyReader.getProperty("login_page"))));
        this.loginPage.clearForm();
    }
}
}
```

BaseTest

```
public class BaseTest {

public WebDriver webDriver;
protected LoginPage loginPage;
protected HomePage homePage;
protected PolicyPage policyPage;

private String getDriverPath() {
    return "path\\chromedriver.exe";
}

@BeforeSuite
private void beginTest() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", this.getDriverPath());
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("keep-alive-for-test");
    options.addArguments("dns-prefetch-disable");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    //capabilities.setCapability(ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    this.webDriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    this.loginPage = navigateToLoginPage();
    this.homePage = PageFactory.initElements(this.getDriver(), HomePage.class);

}

protected LoginPage navigateToLoginPage() {
    navigateTo(mylink);
    return PageFactory.initElements(this.getDriver(), LoginPage.class);
}

private void navigateTo(String url) {
    this.getDriver().navigate().to(url);
}

private WebDriver getDriver() {
    return this.webDriver;
}
}
```

BasePage

```
public class BasePage {

protected WebDriver driver;

public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}
}
```

Here is the exception output

```
Tests run: 3, Failures: 3, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 9.527 sec 
<<< FAILURE!
login(login.LoginPageTest)  Time elapsed: 0.007 sec  <<< FAİLURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
at login.LoginPageTest.login(LoginPageTest.java:21)

login(login.LoginPageTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< FAİLURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
at login.LoginPageTest.login(LoginPageTest.java:21)

login(login.LoginPageTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< FAİLURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
at login.LoginPageTest.login(LoginPageTest.java:17)
```

It first run the beginTest method and then browser get opened without any problem. Then the login page opens and it just pops exception without any login text area input entrance. Can it be caused of any annotation problem?

Comment: I suggest modify beginTest() from private to public. In addition change annotation to @BeforeClass

Comment: @kaanbobac yes this solved my problem in a degree but I cannot do any operation on home page with web elements.